# MAMP server is not responding to api post request correctly: Internal Server Error 500: „Call to a member function search() on null“

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controller, shopware

I am following a course about shopware 6 on how to display data throughout the storefront, which would be provided with an API controller. I already checked the code multiple times with the tutorial code and I can not find any mistakes. The API client Insomnia is able to recognize the API route, nevertheless, the server responds with an internal server error.

```
public function generate(Context $context): Response
{
    $faker = Factory::create();
    $country = $this->getActiveCountry($context);
    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $data[] = [
            'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
            'active' => true,
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'street' => $faker->streetAddress,
            'postCode' => $faker->postcode,
            'city' => $faker->city,
            'countryId' => $country->getId(),
        ];
    }
    $this->shopFinderRepository->create($data, $context);


    return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

In fact I am quite new to symfony and I am not able to read and understand the code fluently the function getActiveCountry(). I assume I missed something in this function.
The respond what I should be getting is 204 HTTP_NO_CONTENT. If someone could clarify this code block for me and resolve this error, I would appreciate it a lot.

Domain Route (proposed by the [shopware 6](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/api-controller) Docs.):

```
@RouteScope({"api"});
```

Admin API:

```
* @Route("/api/v{version}/_action/swag-shop-finder/generate", name="api.custom.swag_shop_finder.generate", methods={"POST"})
```

The API controller is registered in a services.xml and a seperate routes.xml file:

```
 <service id="SwagShopFinder\Core\Api\DemoDataController" public="true">
        <argument id="country.repository" type="service" />
        <argument id="swag_shop_finder.repository" type="service" />
        <call method="setContainer">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </call>
    </service>
```

routes.xml file:

```
 <import resource="../../**/Api/*Controller.php" type="annotation" />
```

Error Message:

```
"code": "0",
  "status": "500",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "detail": "Call to a member function search() on null"

"file": "\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/shopware6_testing\/custom\/plugins\/SwagShopFinder\/src\/Core\/Api\/DemoDataController.php",
        "line": 63,
        "function": "getActiveCountry",
        "class": "SwagShopFinder\\Core\\Api\\DemoDataController",
        "type": "->",
```

Line 94:

```
 /**
 * @param Context $context
 * @return CountryEntity
 * @throws CountryNotFoundException
 * @throws InconsistentCriteriaIdsException
 */
private function getActiveCountry(Context $context): CountryEntity
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', '1'));
    $criteria->setLimit(1);

    $country = $this->countryRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities()->first();
    if ($country === null) {
        throw new CountryNotFoundException('');
    }
    return $country;
}
```

Comment: In your `DemoDataController` line 63 there is a null variable on which you try to call a `search` method. This is the code we need to help you find why.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response first of all! I will send the rest.